# Google maps API issue, center on specific position on NativeScript App

Tags: javascript, google-maps, nativescript

I am trying to make an uber type app with nativescript but I am struggling to find a way to center a position when an app opens just like when you open uber app. I am using google maps API

Thank you

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly. It does not become clear what your code looks like, what plugins you consume, and how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the nativescript-google-maps-sdk (which I think you are since you also posted the question over there) then you can do this:

```
// Any value from 2 to 20
mapView.zoom = 15;

// Moves the map
mapView.latitude = lat;
mapView.longitude = lng;

// Places the marker at the point
marker.position = mapsModule.Position.positionFromLatLng(lat, lng);
```